# Why is the inverse of this chart analytic?

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, differential-geometry, differential-topology

I'm currently going through Differential Topology by Hirsch. While motivating the concept of a chart, the book claims that the map $$\phi : U \to B$$ defined by $\phi (x_1,x_2,x_3) = (x_1,x_2)$ is a homeomorphism where $U \subset S^2$(unit sphere) defined $U=\{ (x_1,x_2,x_3) \in S^2 : x_3>0\}$ and $B$ is the open disk in $\Bbb R^2$. The book further claims that the inverse of $\phi$ is analytic. I don't know how to justify these claims. Any insight into the matter will be appreciated.

Comment: Well, just write down the inverse map and check by hand that it has those properties. You know that $x_1^2+x_2^2+x_3^2 =1$, now you can solve for $x_3$.

Comment: If you hate the square root too much, you can also use the implicit function theorem to show that $\phi$ is locally bi-analytic :) but that seems like an overkill

Comment: @SeverinSchraven Bijective and locally bi-analytic thus the global inverse is everywhere locally analytic thus globally analytic

Comment: @reuns Indeed, but that was meant as a joke. For showing that it is bijective one needs anyway to compute the inverse. And checking that $(x_1, x_2) \mapsto (x_1, x_2, \sqrt{1-x_1^2 - x_2^2})$ is analytic is certainly more convenient than invoking the implicit function theorem :)

Comment: @SeverinSchraven Why not an official anmswer?

Comment: @PaulFrost I feel that the OP learns more if he writes the answer himself using my comments. Then he also gets feedback whether he understood it correctly and earns some reputation